# Regex replace - Conditionally adding characters

Tags: regex

I am trying to do a regex find and replace, but in the replacement, I want to add a character only if a match was found for one of the matching groups. For example:

For the text `ab` I am using the regex `(a)?(b)?` to match multiple groups. I want the result to be replaced with `\1.\2` to produce `a.b` if and only if `b` is actually found. In the case that only `a` is found, the result should **not** contain the period, i.e. just `a`.

I know this can be done in two steps, but is this kind of conditional insert possible with a single regex statement?

**EDIT**

I oversimplified my test case a bit. My real situation is as follows:

I need to match `name="name" property="property"` in any order (the name field can come first or last.

I then want to replace it with `value="name.property"` or simply `value="name"` in the case property is not found.

Comment: What language/tool are you using?

Comment: Doing a search and replace on a JSP in Eclipse and/or Notepad++

Comment: It is not possible to do with 1 pass in Notepad++ or any tools like this because you need a callback/Match Evaluator/... to check for the group that matched. Either 2 regexes, or use a full-fledged programmed solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in several comments, there is no way to do this in a basic text editor's search and replace. It can only be done with callbacks or external code.

I ended up just doing it in two steps: Replace with `\1.\2`, and then search and replace any dangling periods.

Answer (score 1):

Do it in multiple steps. First do the replacements that find both strings:

```
s/name="(.*?)" property="(.*?)"/value="\1.\2"/
s/property="(.*?)" name="(.*?)"/value="\2.\1"/
```

Then replace the ones that are left with just the one string:

```
s/name="(.*)"/value="\1"/
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible:

**[Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bC3nH2/1)**

```
([a])?[b](?(1)[c]|[d])
```

http://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html

Comment: What's the replacement string? The question is about doing a match and replace, and the replacement is conditional on which parts of the regexp matched.

Comment: Yes, *matching* the input is merely tricky; generating the correct replacement is impossible.  As others have said, it would require callbacks or external code, neither of which is usually available in a text editor's search/replace feature.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of replacement string conditionals are directly supported by JGsoft V2, Boost, and PCRE2 according to [Regular-Expressions.info](https://www.regular-expressions.info/replaceconditional.html). For Boost and PCRE2 syntax is different and JGsoft V2 supports both syntaxes.

For replacement string conditionals to work in Boost, you need to pass `regex_constants::format_all` to `regex_replace`. For PCRE2, you need to pass `PCRE2_SUBSTITUTE_EXTENDED` to `pcre2_substitute`.

Boost’s syntax is `(?1matched:unmatched)` where 1 is a number between 1 and 99 referencing a numbered capturing group.

PCRE2’s syntax is `${1:+matched:unmatched}` where 1 is a number between 1 and 99 referencing a numbered capturing group.